# Find brighter areas in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, game-automation

I am trying to find the direction the player camera is facing so I can rotate it. The direction is given on the minimap by a cone where the area is brighter. You can see it better in the images below.

[image]

[image]

As you can see it's a cone that makes the minimap slightly brighter on the side it is facing. What I am trying to do is basically find the closest blue dot on the minimap and rotate the camera towards it, I did the first part (finding the closest blue dot) but I don't know how to actually rotate the camera towards it.

What is the best way to find the direction the camera is facing at the current moment? Thx

PS: I am currently using cv2

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/find-brighter-area-in-an-image/13800